# Combine/ "concatenate" two variables, one being a user input

Tags: python

I am looking to combine a user inputted string as one variable (it is dynamic, of course) and use it to make another variable.

Example:

```
x = str(input("What do you want to buy? "))
```

(I want the new variable to be like `x_cost` - but of course you don't actually write that)

Let's say that the user inputs apple, so the new variable would be: `apple_cost`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Don't.  Use a dict instead.

Comment: How do I use a dict?

Comment: Why can't you just do `apple_cost = str(input('Price? '))`?

Comment: why do you want to do that? whats the requirement? you could use class properties with setattr if you have to but using user input to be variables is a bad idea

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Because there will be multiple inputs, say apple, pear and peach, and I want the new variable to be easy to read. Also, there will be math equations underneath that uses the different fruits to calculate different costs. Does that make sense? Sorry, I'm quite new to programming.

Comment: Then yes, use a dictionary. Just Google "python dictionary" and you'll find lots of information on it.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Can you tell me how I would use setattr in my problem?

Comment: Like I said, you can Google this and find lots of basic information that would explain what it's all about. SO does expect you to do at least some research on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a dict for this. I get that it can be hard to understand what a dict is if you've never seen it before, but if you want to learn, it's absolutely necessary to slow down and understand these things.

```
costs = {}

item_name = input("What do you want to buy? ")
costs[item_name] = input('Price? ')
```

So you can try and enter a few things

```
costs = {}

for i in range(4):    
    item_name = input("What do you want to buy? ")
    costs[item_name] = input('Price? ')
```

How would you print out all these new variables if you don't know the names? With a dict it is easy:

```
for key, value in costs.items():
    print(key, "costs", value)
```

Comment: This makes sense to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A good way of solving this problem would be to use a dictionary.  A dictionary "entry" holds two objects, a key and an item. You can think of the key as the magic word and the item as the genie--by calling the key (i.e. saying the magic words) you can reference an item (i.e. summoning the genie).

Let's go with the fruit example. If you want the user to input one of three fruits (lets say `apple`, `pear`, and `cantaloupe`) and have it correspond to a price. If we say the apple costs one dollar, the pear two, and the cantaloupe one hundred, then here is what our dictionary would look like:

```
#This is our dictionary. you can see the keyword (the fruit) goes first
#in order to summon the price, which we will store in another variable
fruit_dict = {'apple': 1.00, 'pear': 2.00, `cantaloupe`: 100.00}
```

Now that we have a working dictionary, let us write a program!

```
#First we define the dictionary
fruit_dict = {"apple": 1.00, "pear": 2.00, "cantaloupe": 100.00}

#Now we need to ask for user input
fruit = raw_input("What fruit would ya like?\n>>> ")

#Next, we look for the fruit in our dictionary. We will use a function 
#called `values()`, which returns `True` or `False`. 
if fruit in fruit_dict:
    fruit_cost = fruit_dict[fruit] #accessing the value with dictname[key]
```

Easy as that! Now you can do what you want with the variable.

Best of luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create variable names dynamically.

What you need is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

There are two ways to achieve what you want

```
mydict = {}

x = str(input("What do you want to buy? "))

mydict[str(x)+'_cost'] = 'some value'
```

Now using user input directly to populate a dictionary can be a risky business from security point of view, so you may want do:

```
import hashlib
mydict = {}

x = str(input("What do you want to buy? "))
hashkey = hashlib.md5(str(x)).hexdigest()
mydict[hashkey+'_cost'] = 'some value'
```

Answer (score 0):

In python everything is object. A program starts in a main module **main**. Each module, class, etc has its own namespace (a dictionary) where variables are defined. So if you put a key in that namespace dict then it becomes variable. You can make use of that variable to point to any other object you want.

Just look at this code...

try this in python interactive mode....

`import sys`

`sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__  # this is your main modules namespace.`

So just push the name of variable into the dict as key and assign the value/object.

`sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__['apple_cost']]`

`apple_cost = 10.5`

You can access the namespace of any containers class/modules/etc... But I would not suggest you to do what I explained (this is just one way of doing it. little bit hacky/ugly) instead use descriptors or simple getattr method in a class  (bit advanced but something useful to learn) to implement some thing like this.